# Seed eloquent event to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have mapped eloquent event to dedicated class and now I want to seed this event to mysql table.

In my Radar model eloquent event look like this:

```
protected $events = [

    'created' => RadarWasCreated::class,

];
```

How can I describe this event in migration ant seed files to track this event in mysql table?

Comment: What do you mean by "seeding this event to the mysql table"?

Comment: Events are broadcast across your application but don't "do" anything, they just pass data.  If you want to perform an action on a event, you need to create a listener/handler.

Comment: I want to connect this event with my mysql table column @GiamPy

Comment: Yes, I have created a listener too, but I can't figure out how to connect this listener to db table @Devon

Comment: The same way you  would connect any part of your application to a db table... through a model or a query.

Comment: I still don't get what your goal is. Do you want to store a new entry in a table everytime an event is triggered?

Comment: That's the thing, I already described event and listener to Radar model, but I can't figure out how to call it in migration file @Devon

Comment: Yes, I want to log information to mysql table whenever user creates something. @GiamPy

Comment: @Luke why would you be calling it in a migration file?

Comment: I want to create column in table, in which event will be stored whenever user creates something. It's like logging, to track user activity, what he is creating, updating, deleting and etc. @Devon

Comment: So you want to create a new column everytime this Event is broadcasted?  Seems strange, but still not a use for a migration.  Migrations shouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: No, I only want to store information in this column, for example in column 'who' I want to store which user created something. @Devon

Comment: @Luke I think you need to do some more reading into Laravel.  Migrations are used to create tables, not insert data.